Should requests for code that implements some method relevant to QF be on-topic?
Should requests for code that implement some method relevant to the field be considered on-topic? An answer to such a question could consist of just the (pseudo)-code or a link to a full implementation.

Thanks for the input, I believe there is a high degree of agreement within the community to allow this type of question if the OP puts in sufficient effort.

Of course it's on topic. Why not? As long as it's about quantitative finance and not too basic like asking how to discount a single cashflow. Sharing source code will help everybody.

It depends how it's asked obviously.
If the question shows enough effort was done and points out to a specific problem, then yes.
If the question is blunt and just asks for the code, then no.
I think a question about best implementations of different methods (like "which library is recommended for XXX") is fine as well.
